# Getting gray question marks on serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I am trying to use an arduino uno to check to see if an esp8266-015 wifi module is working using AT commands.
Connections
ESP8266 Arduino
Rx-Rx
Tx-Tx
GND-GND
EN-3.3v
VDD-3.3

I selected arduino uno in my board manager and the correct port
this code is just a setup and loop

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

But when I type AT into the serial monitor, nothing happens, All I see is the serial monitor spitting this.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLGjE.png)

I have looked through several tutorials and I keep getting this error, it just keeps printing the gray question marks. This is my first time using an esp8266 wifi module.

Comment: select 115200 baud

Comment: I did that it still produced that output

Comment: Arduino TX -> ESP8266 RX, Arduino RX <- ESP8266 TX. You need to connect the sender to receiver, not RX - RX, TX - TX.

Comment: @hcheung, the esp8266 communicates with the USB chip of Uno, not with the ATmega

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the serial monitor first in your code, otherwise it won't be readable. Putting:

```
Serial.begin(115200);
```

Within the setup loop should allow this to be readable, but you can also add extra processing as shown at this link: https://www.instructables.com/Get-Started-With-ESP8266-Using-AT-Commands-Via-Ard/